# How to compare two file in bash script and find lines in one file not in another?

Tags: bash, shell

For example, I have two files. They are not sorted.
File1:

```
apple
banana
pineapple
```

File2:

```
pineapple
blueberry
banana
```

I want to echo fruits that only exist in file1, not in file2. And in this case, it's apple.(even we have pineapple)

Comment: Do you need your output to respect the current ordering of items in the files, or is it fine if the output is in sorted order?

Comment: Also, what do you know about the real-world size bounds? Is it possible for the files to be too large to fit in memory? Too large to have temporary copies made on disk?

Comment: ...mind, in pretty much any case the answer you end up with will be either `comm` or `awk` (in the former case, with transient `sort` invocations for both inputs).